# Can I get summary of test case from TestLink with TestLink-API-Python-client

Tags: python, testlink

Are there any ways to get summary of test case from TestLink  with TestLink-API-Python-client?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use following:

```
>>> print tls.whatArgs('getTestCase')
getTestCase(<testcaseid>, [testcaseexternalid=<testcaseexternalid>], [version=<version>], [devKey=<devKey>])
 get test case specification using external or internal id

        attention - be careful with testcaseexternalid - it must include an '-'.
        otherwise TL (<=1.9.8) returns
        <ProtocolError for xmlrpc.php: 500 Internal Server Error>
```